# Fix library for .NET

Tags: c#, fix-protocol

I am looking for a recommendation for a [FIX](http://www.fixprotocol.org/) library for .Net (C#).
It should support [FIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIX_protocol) and possibly FIXML.

I already know of [QuickFix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/documentation.html), but it has [some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163970/dll-runtime-error-crashes-my-c-app-how-to-avoid-it) which I'd like to avoid.

Ideas?

Comment: Would a version for VB.NET be ok?

Comment: @John: As long as it's .Net it should be OK - clearly a full C# implementation is preferable, and also C# examples would be nice (but not, strictly speaking, necessary).

Comment: @Skli: then I'm curious why you specified "for C#"?

Comment: @John: because it's a c# project and I'd much prefer to only have to deal with only c# source. It's the core skill of the team.

Comment: @dumbcoder: well, I don't need any "alibi" to "steer away" from anything. I simply weigh the pros and cons and then choose the best alternative - considering the constraints I have, like skills, uptime, cost of fixing stuff etc.

Comment: @Skliwz: you didn't specify that you needed source. You should update your question to say so.

Comment: @john, in fact, i don't need the source of the library necessarily (but I would like example source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally settled on [RapidAddition](http://www.rapidaddition.com/).

> The RA–Cub FIX engine is an entry level FIX engine designed to give new entrants an affordable flexibility. RA-Cub provides a smooth upgrade to the RA-Cheetah FIX Engine so transition to a low-latency engine later on, should it be required, is a simple operation, requiring no new Systems Integration effort.
>
> RA-Cub is available both as a .NET/C# FIX Engine and as a Java FIX Engine, with both versions being deployable to multiple environments.

It worked quite well for us.

Answer (score 7):

Best FIX library for .Net (C#) is **QuickFIX** .You can use it for getting  your requirements.
If you find some bugs ,then you can post it on QuickFIX forum ,they people solve it without any cost.i am using it for more than 2 years.

**VersaFix** is also second alternative for you .You can also use it with .Net plateform.It 
has almost same feature as QuickFIX.You can get source code an others from VersaFIX link.

If you are looking for third party dll(library) ,it depends upon your requirement and subscription types and times.But [**Onixs**](http://www.onixs.biz/) has a very good api for your requirement and it is bug free with very good support.

Other third party API for FIX implementation **QXFIX** from ModulusFE .It is very new FIX engine having all features like support for all updated versions of FIX and FAST.

**[FIX Antenna](http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/fix_engines/fix_enginenet.aspx)**  is Other alternative for you ,supports all FIX versions and FAST 1.1 without any bug :-) ,good with .Net for fast data transfer on network.

Comment: I don't think QuickFIX is the "best" FIX library, as the code base is a mess. E.g. there is no way to synchronize the login process without doing some hackish things (SocketInitiator.Start() is no blocking function, nor async)

Comment: Try quickfixn for C# (https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn).

Comment: Thank you for stating VersaFIX which is under BSD license. And that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of commercial fix engine.

If you need something open source try:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fix4net/

Comment: it seems to be a dead project...

Answer (score 0):

A few factoids for you. The two most performant solutions for .Net are from Rapid addition and Onix.

There is some variance in the functionality offered and the pricing models, you can make your own decision.

http://www.rapidaddition.com/

http://www.onixs.biz/

Both were very helpful with evaluation code and test cases.